# Symfony FOS routes not updating properly for change-password

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, routes, fosuserbundle

I have a symfony project using **FOS User Bundle** for handling using.

I want to modify the default routes stored in `app/config/routing.yml`

Now changing all of the routes seems to work fine, apart from the *change_password.xml*

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /psswd
# this prefix value throws GET error. 
# without the previx '/change-password` works fine
```

Changing anything in the *prefix* gives me the Get not found error for route

> No route found for "GET /psswd"

I have cleared the cache and everything seems to work fine.

Can anyone tell me why such problem would occur?

### Update

It turns out path `/psswd` doesn't work **but** path '/psswd/change-password` works fine :I

Comment: can you share all your route.yml and please share with us did you override the bundle ? if you override please share child bundle route.yml

another point is if you are in the development environment you have to --env=dev  argument for cache clearing.

Comment: I'm editing the `routing.yml` file directly. Check question update

Comment: I checked mine env. /psswd is not work because directly. because it's a prefix. try to /psswd/change-password